# KeyError: "The name 'predictions' refers to an Operation not in the graph."

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, face-recognition, keyerror

I have a class `FaceDetector` and some methods such as neural net, build_model, predict and etc.

When writing the below code, I'm running into the error mentioned in the title:

```py
graph = tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph()
all_names = [op.name for op in graph.get_operations()]
print('y_pred' in all_names)
input_x = graph.get_tensor_by_name("input_x:0")
y_pred = graph.get_operation_by_name("predictions").outputs[0]`
```

Anyway, my variable `y_pred` is not defined in the scope of the function/method this code exists.

My code with y_pred is as follows:

```py
y_pred = self.neural_net(input_x)`
```

where `neural_net` has two hidden layers and a fully connected output layer.

I'm running another script called 'predict.py' which in turn calls  this present script.

Need some help here..

The predict method which contains this above code is as follows:

```py
def predict(self, X_valid, y_valid):
        """
        Returns a dictionary containing the model's predictions as well as the ground truth,
        encoded as integers

        Positional arguments:

            X_valid -- the validation samples, as numpy flat ndarray

            y_valid -- the validation labels, as one-hot-encoded arrays

        """
        sess=tf.compat.v1.Session()   
        saver = tf.compat.v1.train.import_meta_graph(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'saved_model','my_test_model.meta'))
        saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'saved_model')))


        graph = tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph()
        # for op in graph.get_operations():
        #     print(str(op.name))
        all_names = [op.name for op in graph.get_operations()]
        print('y_pred' in all_names)
        input_x = graph.get_tensor_by_name("input_x:0")
        y_pred = graph.get_operation_by_name("predictions").outputs[0]

        print("\nMaking predictions...:")

        predi_list = []
        ground_truth_list = []

        print("running sess")
        predi =sess.run(y_pred, feed_dict={input_x:X_valid})
        predi_list += list(predi)
        ground_truth_list +=  [np.argmax(item) for item in y_valid]

        pred_dic ={}
        ground_truth = [np.argmax(item) for item in y_valid]
        pred_dic = {'predictions':list(predi), 'ground_truth':ground_truth }
        return pred_dic`
```

Comment: We cannot really help you without more information, where is the predictions operation defined?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I'm reading and implementing an unknown code to learn and explore tensorflow. predictions operation is nowhere defined in the project. So, I'm confused about what this line is doing exactly and what to do. If possible can you please explain this part of the code. I will try and reach out in case of any further problems.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I have edited the question. Please look into it and respond.